# How to apply a given XSLT sheet template for a Word Document

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word

I have been given an XSLT File to use for my Diploma Project document.I don't know how to use it.Can someone please  guide me how to use and what effect can I expect in my document after using it.
Sorry if I sound stupid, but i couldn't get any information anywhere.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This isn't a tutorial site. Ask the person who gave you the XSLT file what you're supposed to do with it, or find a tutorial on Google or W3C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting wikipedia

> XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations) is a language for transforming XML documents into other XML documents, or other formats such as HTML for web pages, plain text or XSL Formatting Objects, which may subsequently be converted to other formats, such as PDF, PostScript and PNG.

Suppose you save your all data in an XML file

```
<card xmlns="http://businesscard.org">
   <name>John Doe</name>
   <title>CEO, Widget Inc.</title>
   <email>john.doe@widget.com</email>
   <phone>(202) 456-1414</phone>
   <phone>(202) 456-2345</phone>
</card>
```

Later you decide you want to create a website, displaying that in some table or something. You can avoid manual copy, paste by using xslt. Just write an Xsl for it, parse with some xslt parser. Your web page will be completed easily.

Later you want to create a pdf or another xml where you only need say, name and phone numbers only, xslt will help you do that too.

**tutorial** : [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xslt/xslt_syntax.htm)